# Embedding https links in the figure ref captions of rbookdown

Tags: r, figure, ref, bookdown

Not sure how this is to be done, but I have a few citations and a source link in the caption for an image. However, the following doesn't seem to work:

````
(ref:my-caption) This is a [google link](https://google.com) in the caption of the figure.

```{r gim, fig.cap="(ref:my-caption)", fig.align='center', fig.asp=0.75, echo=FALSE, out.width='85%'}
knitr::include_graphics("./google-images.png")
```
````

The error from rbookdown build included:

```
! Argument of \caption@ydblarg has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.338 ...ogle link} in the caption of the figure.}
                                                  \label{fig:gim}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

````
```{r gim, fig.cap=paste(ref_caption), fig.align='center', fig.asp=0.75, echo=FALSE, out.width='85%'}

ref_caption <- "This is a \\href{https://google.com}{google link} in the caption of the figure."

knitr::include_graphics("./google-images.png")
```
````

Comment: This Surely Helped! :D. Thanks :)

Comment: Nice, thanks. Welcome to SO, @Subbu. Could you please confirm my answer and upvote it? Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

While the solution offered by @bttomio didn't solve the problem entirely, a small modification to the same did all the magic! I followed up on the solution offered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228973/argument-of-captionydblarg-has-an-extra), and the following works:

````
```{r gim, fig.cap=paste(ref_caption), fig.align='center', fig.asp=0.75, echo=FALSE, out.width='85%'}

ref_caption <- "This is a \\protect\\href{https://google.com}{google link} in the caption of the figure."

knitr::include_graphics("./google-images.png")
```
````